# How is mvn:branch used when I want to release a git flow based project with release:perform

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

Earlier we used mvn release:prepare and release:perform to release a version. 
Now we swiched to use git flow and want to build with bamboo. The problem is that with the use of release:prepare, the version on the master(version) branch is updated and that change would have to be merged back to dev branch, which cannot be made with any automation.

So I looked around and found that release:branch makes a new branch for my version and does the changes there, which is perfectly ok for me. But what now? I cannot make a release:perform because rlease:branch is not doing the preparation work that release:perform does. No release.properties are written and so the command fails with some errors regarding the VCS information.

Has anyone figured out how these steps are thought to be used?

Comment: By using some gitflow maven plugin for doing releases?

Comment: that is of course an option, but I want to know how the maven-release-plugin is supposed to work. Someone must have an intention to provide a goal release:branch. I cannot find a documentation or example that answers my questions. I also opened an issue in their jira, without an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. first used release:prepare and release:perform on the develop branch, and then created a release branch from the tag

```
 mvn --batch-mode\
 -DreleaseVersion=${env.RELEASE_VERSION}\
 -DdevelopmentVersion=${env.DEVELOPMENT_VERSION}\
 release:prepare release:perform

git checkout tags/release-${env.RELEASE_VERSION} -b release/${env.RELEASE_VERSION}
git push origin release/${env.RELEASE_VERSION}
```